# cumulative value across monthly periods

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following sql query that:

```
with all_stock as ( 
  select distinct stock_items.item_id,
stock_item.owner,
stock_item.group
from stock_item
),
balances as 
(select 
b.year,
b.month,
b.item_id,
sum(balance) as balance_value,
from balances_table b
group by 
b.year,
b.month,
b.item_id
), transactions_1 AS (
select t.month, t.year, t.item_id, t.value as t_value
from transactions_table t
where type = 1
group by t.year, t.month, t.item_id
), transactions_2 AS (
select t.month, t.year, t.item_id, t.value as t_value
from transactions_table t
where type = 2
groupy by t.year,t.period, t.item_id
), transactions_3 AS (
select t.month, t.year, t.item_id, t.value as t_value
from transactions t
where type = 3
group by t.year, t.period, t.item_id
)
select 
all_stock.group,
all_stock.owner,
all_stock.item_id,
current_bal.year,
current_bal.month,
coalesce(opening_bal.balance_value, 0) as opening_balance,
coalesce(current_bal.balance_value, 0) as balance_value,
coalesce(previous_bal.balance_value, 0) as previous_blance_value,
sum(coalesce(transactions_1.t_value,0)) as type_1_value,
sum(coalesce(transactions_2.t_value,0)) as type_2_value,
sum(coalesce(transactions_3.t_value,0)) as type_3_value,
coalesce(current_bal.balance_value,0) - coalesce(opening_bal.balance_value,0) - (sum(coalesce(transactions_1.t_value,0) + sum(coalesce(transactions_2.t_value, 0) + sum(coalesce(transactions_3.t_value,0)) as difference

from all_stock
left join balances current_bal
on (all_stock.item_id = current_bal.item_id)
left join balances previous_bal 
on (current_bal.item_id = previous_bal.item_id
and current_bal.month - 1 = previous_bal.month
and current_bal.year = previous_bal.year
)
left join balances opening_bal
on (all_stock.item_id = opening_bal.item_id
and opening_bal.month = '0'
and current_bal.year = previous_bal.year)

left join transactions_1
on ( current_bal.item_id = transactions_1.item_id
and current_bal.month  >= transactions_1.month
and current_bal.year = transactions_1.year
) 
left join transactions_2
on (current_bal.item_id = transactions_2.item_id
and current_bal.month >= transactions_2.month
and current_bal.year = transactions_2.year
)
left join transactions_3
on (current_bal.item_id = transactions_3.item_id
and current_bal.month >= transactions_3.month
and current_bal.year = transactions_3.year)

where current_bal > 0

group by 
all_stock.group,
all_stock.owner,
all_stock.item_id,
current_bal.year,
current_bal.month,
coalesce(opening_bal.balance_value, 0),
coalesce(current_bal.balance_value, 0),
coalesce(previous_bal.balance_value, 0);
```

I am trying to show a cumulative value for all transactions types (1,2,3) across all months. So If I'm in month 5 then I want all transactions_1, transactions_2, transactions_3 to be cumulating values from month 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

The query that I currently have does not do that. Anyone has any idea how I can achieve that.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Here's a sample output:

```
GROUP   OWNER   ITEM_ID     YEAR    MONTH   OPENING_BAL BALANCE_VALUE TRANS_1   TRANS_2 TRANS_3 DIFFERENCE

                 12313      2016      1     67450.11    64564.97                         -2486.64   -398.5  
                 12313      2016      2     67450.11    61831.26                         -2135.96   -3482.89
```

The DIFFERENCE which is the one i'm after is calculated by the following sql line:

```
coalesce(opening_bal.balance_value,0) - (sum(coalesce(transactions_1.t_value,0) + sum(coalesce(transactions_2.t_value, 0) + sum(coalesce(transactions_3.t_value,0)) as difference
```

The calculation is done using only transactions from each respective month. For instance, for month 2 we have -3482.89 which is incorrect as that is only getting the transa_1,2,3 from month 2 and ignoring the ones in month 1.  However the DIFFERENCE value for Month = 2 should actually be approximately -998 (not including the decimals).

This value is coming from the doing the following calculation: Current_bal - opening_bal - (transactions_1 + transactions_2 + transactions_3 in each month).

Comment: Provide sample data and desire output so we can help you.

Comment: Can you please review the question now and remove the -1. I've provided enough details now. Thank you.

Comment: You still havent provide sample data. Also if you put your code in http://poorsql.com/ cant be formated properly because bad sintaxis.

Comment: @bytebiscuit You may think you have, but you haven't - we can't run your sql because we don't have your tables or data. Either prune your query into a much simpler example that still demonstrates your issue and provide the sample data (preferably as either create table + insert statements, or as a `with` clause) or provide all the create table and insert statements for the tables referenced in your big query. Either way, if you're wanting to use values from other rows, you're looking at using analytic functions. I suggest you google something like "oracle cumulative sum analytic function"

Comment: Hi boneist that's what I'm looking for yes. Thank you anyways. You may close the question. I'll browse around.

Comment: @bytebiscuit we dont want close your question. We are trying to guide you on how make a better question so you can get usefull answer. A simple data sample and desire output will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Simple cumulative ([analytic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions182.htm#SQLRF06115)) sums:

```
SELECT reset
     , criteria
     , date_col
     , trunc(date_col,'year') year_col
     , columns_to
     , sort_by
     , metric
     , SUM(metric) OVER (PARTITION BY reset, criteria, trunc(date_col,'year') 
                             ORDER BY columns_to, sort_by) AS cum_metric
  FROM your_tables;
```